# How to find the last personage in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 4 arrays with several personages

```
var p1 = ['Tya', 21 ];
var p2 = ['Milo', 30];
var p3 = ['Lili', 15];
var persos = [p1,p2,p3];
```

The option 1 allows to visualize my personages

```
case 1 : console.log("Option 1 - Display personage \n");
            
         for(var i=0; i<persos.length; i++){
            console.log("*****************");
            console.log("Personage n° " + (i+1));
            console.log("Name : " + persos[i][0]);
            console.log("Age : " + persos[i][1]);
          }
break;
```

The option 3 allows to delete the last personage.
In my example, I have to retrieve the personage `Lili`.

I don't understand how to make this.

```
case 3 : console.log("Option 4 - Delete personnage\n");
           if(persos.length > 0){
              for(var i=0; i<persos.length-1; i++){
                console.log("Name " + persos[persos.length-1]);
                console.log("*****************");
            }

          }
break;
```

I want to know how to retrieve the last personage and the values: `Lili` and `15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is retrieving the last element of the array, you dont need to loop over, you can just do something like

```js
case 3 : console.log("Option 4 - Delete personnage\n");
           if(persos.length > 0){
              const lastItem = persos[persons.length - 1] // this will be lily
              console.log(`age is ${lastItem[1]}`)
              console.log(`name is ${lastItem[0]}`)
              persos.pop(); // this will remove the last element
          }
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to retrieve and remove the last element.

```js
var p1 = ['Tya', 21 ];
var p2 = ['Milo', 30];
var p3 = ['Lili', 15];
var persos = [p1,p2,p3];
var last = persos.pop();
console.log('Name:', last[0], 'Age:', last[1]);
```

Comment: @AdriSolid From the question: "The option 3 allows to delete the last personage."

Answer (score 1):

you can use Array#slice func this way:

```
var p1 = ['Tya', 21 ];
var p2 = ['Milo', 30];
var p3 = ['Lili', 15];
var persos = [p1,p2,p3];
var last = persos.slice(-1)[0];
console.log('Name:', last[0], 'Age:', last[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
const p1 = ["Tya", 21];
const p2 = ["Milo", 30];
const p3 = ["Lili", 15];
const persos = [p1, p2, p3];

const lastElement = persos[persos.length - 1];
console.log(lastElement); // ["Lili", 15]

const [lastElementName, lastElementAge] = lastElement;
console.log(lastElementName); // Lili
console.log(lastElementAge); // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve last value of array without modifying said array you can do `arr[arr.length - 1]`.

Your array indexes from 0, so first element would be `persos[0]`. Since length indicates amount (i.e. if array have one element, its length will be `1`), you can subtract 1 from length and get index of last element.

If you want to retrieve last element and delete it from array, you should use method [`.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)